# Can't FTP into server

Tags: linux, centos

I need to FTP in from one server to another

If I FTP using my local PC using Krusader I'm able to FTP into the server

but if I ssh into one server and I'm trying to FTP to the server using the same ftp credentials I get message [Resolving host address...]

I know this address is correct since I can ping it from the server

I use the following command

```
lftp 'open -u username,password server'
```

If I use the same command to ftp to a different server it works.

Any help advise will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is FTP a requirement? Otherwise I would strongly recommend using sftp to transfer the files instead. Almost all ssh daemons support sftp. That way you avoid all the problems with FTP (including firewalls, passwords in clear text, no confidentiality, no integrity checks and so on). Even if you don't worry about somebody seeing the data the lack of integrity protection is nasty when transfering data between servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this might be obvious but try using the IP instead of the hostname

```
lftp 'open -u username,password IP'
```

from the output

> `[Resolving host address...]`

It seems that lftp has some trouble resolving the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall between the two servers that is preventing FTP?

And I'm with pehrs, use ssh

\\Greg

Answer (score 0):

If I can use ssh, I usually just use scp instead of sftp. It's a bit faster on the transfer.